# EF Mapping multiple properties same table. The relationship '' was not loaded because the type '' is not available

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, mapping

I have a class with multiple properties that can be mapped to one table with a different type as property. 
I did this to don't have several tables with the same schema for each property.
As follows:

```
public class Flower : Entity
    {
        public Flower()
        {
            Events = new Collection<Event>();
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public FlowerType Type { get; set; }

        public virtual ExtraInfoBase Family { get; set; }

        public virtual ExtraInfoBase Specie { get; set; }

        public virtual ExtraInfoBase Seller { get; set; }

        public string SellerObs { get; set; }

        public virtual ExtraInfoBase Localization { get; set; }
```

Extrainfobase is a class that can handle all those properties with a diferent type:

```
 public class ExtraInfoBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public InfoType Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Extra { get; set; }
    public virtual Flower Flower { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping as follows:

```
public class FlowerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Flower>
{
    public FlowerMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        this.ToTable("Flowers");

        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasColumnName("Id")
            .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

        this.Property(t => t.Type)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("Type");

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Family).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Flower);

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Gender).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Flower);

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Specie).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Flower);`

public class ExtraInfoBaseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ExtraInfoBase>
{
    public ExtraInfoBaseMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        this.ToTable("ExtraInfo");

        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasColumnName("Id")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(t => t.Type)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("Type");

        this.Property(t => t.Value)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("Value");

        this.Property(t => t.Extra)
            .HasColumnName("Extra");

        this.HasRequired(x => x.Flower);
        this.HasRequired(x => x.User);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error The relationship 'Flower_Family' was not loaded because the type 'ExtraInfoBase' is not available.
What am i doing wrong?
Please advise.

Comment: Does it work if `ExtraInfoBase` inherits from `Entity`?

Comment: Also please include the `User` class in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste your time. I was very tired last night and a possible solution came to me in the sleep. The relations are wrong. Extrainfobase and flower will have a many to many relation so the model is wrong.

Sorry.